# In the Nernst equation $E=E_{cell}-\left(\frac{0.0592V}{n}\right)\log Q$, what does the $E_{cell}$ represent?

Tags: thermodynamics, electric-circuits

In the Nernst equation $$E=E_{Cell}-\left(\frac{0.0592V}{n}\right)\log Q$$
what does the $E_{cell}$ represent? I read that $E_{cell}$ is the standard state condition of the cell, let us say that we have a concentration set up with a larger concentration outside the cell then inside what does the E cell represent.

Comment: Might this question be better asked on the chemistry.stackexchange.com?

Comment: No, it is a physics related question

Comment: It's physical chemistry. I am just saying, as a person who has spent a lot of time on this site, that you will be more likely to get an answer on the other site. Feel free to ignore my recommendation. If you search "Nernst" on this site you get 22 hits; on the chemistry site you get 114...

Answer (score 1):

The Nernst equation is used to determine the voltage of a galvanic cell in non-standard conditions. Standard conditions are standard temperature and $1M$ concentrations in each half-cell. The $E^{\ominus}_{cell}$ represents the voltage of the galvanic cell at these conditions. To calculate, use the definition

$$
E^{\ominus}_{cell} = E^{\ominus}_{red} - E^{\ominus}_{oxd}
$$

where $E_{red}$ is the voltage of the reduction half-reaction (cathode) and $E_{oxd}$ is the voltage of the oxidation half-reaction (anode). By definition $E_{cell}$ is a constant for the specific reaction in the galvanic cell, so it won't change based on concentrations.

If you change the concentrations, you will be changing the reaction quotient, $Q$.

The full [Nernst equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nernst_equation) that can be used to find the cell voltage at any deviation from standard conditions is

$$
E_\text{cell} = E^{\ominus}_\text{cell} - \frac{RT}{zF} \ln{Q_r}.
$$

This really is a [chemistry question](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com).